# android viewpager multiple items untill fill the screen width

Tags: android-viewpager

I'm trying to fill an view pager with as much item as the screen width gets and the last item if it does not fit it will be shown partially. What is the trick settings to do this? My view pager matches the parent with just one item.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do if you add to your ViewPager int the XML file the paddingLeft, paddingRight and clipToPadding atributtes. Try with this example, and replace the padding values for your convenient values:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@+id/center"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="140dp" />
```